# Проблема с SQLite3. Добавление Reference вызывает ошибку. Как решить?

Tags: sqlite, база-данных

Как решить эту проблему?

[image]

Впервые работаю с БД от SQLite3 и сразу вот такая проблема. Что не то? Почему не запускается? Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: ну? никто не заглянет?

Comment: там же все русскими буквами написано

Comment: я понял, но зачем? я это спрашиваю

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека `System.Data.SQLite.dll` полностью зависит от нативной библиотеки sqlite3.dll. Поэтому разрядность системы и установленной библиотеки должны совпадать.
Также обрати внимание на 'Platform target' при компиляции. Она должна быть либо AnyCPU, либо соответствовать требуемой разрядности.